# How to change systemd-resolve daemon global dns temporarily?

Tags: dns, systemd

I can change interface specific dns settings via `resolvectl dns <interface> <ip>` temporarily. How can I achieve this for the global dns? It is explicitly required not to change a config file (e.g. `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`) permanently but rather set the dns temporarily (during runtime of the OS until the next shutdown).

Answer (score 1):

Negative answer: I think it's impossible to set the global DNS and
prevent NetworkManager from adding DNS information without modifying both
`/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` and `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d`.